# Prevent event firing if element has a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have created an ajax load more button that when clicked gets more posts. When the button is clicked a class of loading is added to it and then later removed when all the content has been output.

Is it possible to use the jQuery `:not` selector to stop the click event firing if the button has a class of loading?

Here's a short demo

```
jQuery('#test_btn:not(.clicked)').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('clicked');
    console.log('hi');
});

<div id="test_btn">test<br>button</div>
```

Is this not how you use the `:not` selector? because I am able to fire the click event even when the class of loading is added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using that method of attaching a click event only runs on page load. It never updates.

You should use this:

```js
$(document).on('click','#test_btn:not(.clicked)',function(){
   jQuery(this).addClass('clicked');
    console.log('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test_btn">Click - only works once</button>
```

When you come along later (say, when the ajax call has loaded) and remove the `loading` class from the button, the event will once again work

```js
$(document).on('click','#test_btn:not(.clicked)',function(){
   jQuery(this).addClass('clicked');
    console.log('hi');
});

$(document).on('click','#reset',function(){
   jQuery('#test_btn').removeClass('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test_btn">Click - only works once</button>
<button id="reset">Click to reset</button>
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain why it only tests the :not() selector on page load? Is this event then stored and never checked again? And why does $(document).on ('click' change this?

Comment: @Reece as @Rory alluded to, the `click` is not a delegated handler whereas `on` is. Which means `click` just runs once, but `on` checks the jquery selector every time. This might help: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

As you are dynamically adding the class you need to use a delegated event handler in order for the `:not()` selector to be respected:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#test_btn:not(.clicked)', function() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  console.log('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_btn">test<br>button</div>
```

Alternatively if the sole point of this logic is to only allow the element to be clicked once, just use `one()`:

```js
$('#test_btn:not(.clicked)').one('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  console.log('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_btn">test<br>button</div>
```

Comment: Judging by the description I suspect `loading` is removed later on where they want the event to work again.

Comment: @Jamiec Very true

Comment: Thanks. I replied on Jamiec's post. If you have the time could you answer my questions too?

Comment: It's because in your original example you only bind the event handler when the page loads. At that time no element has the `.clicked` class so they all respond to the click event. Adding the class later has no effect as the event handler has already been bound. Using a delegated event handler means that the selector is instead checked every time the event bubbles up the DOM.